# Strange closure of vi editor

Tags: vi

Upon closing `vi` editor, (without letting it load the whole file),

```
-bash-3.2$ vi /var/spool/mail/user1
-bash-3.2$ 0;136;0c
```

left `0;136;0c` to prompt, what could have made this happen, not letting the `vi` load the contents or what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple of things that keep me from saying definitively what the reason is: first I don't know if you're using `vim`, `vile`, `nvi` or heirloom `vi`. The second thing I don't know is how you closed `vi`, but I'll give a guess.

As far as I know, all `vi` programs use escape sequences to control what appears on the screen. That is, instead of using windowing system calls to position cursors and write text, `vi` uses the value of the TERM environment variable to find out what kind of terminal it has to output to. Based on the value of TERM, it sends special byte sequences, which often or always begin with 0x1b, the ASCII "ESC" or escape character. The special bytes are referred to as "escape sequences".

In the old days, the hardware of the serial terminals would do special things, like move the cursor, or change text colors or fonts, or draw lines, or change to a different character set based on those escape sequences. `vi` still uses them, as far as I know. The whole escape sequence thing has been abstracted into a library called "curses" or "ncurses", which C programs can use.

My guess is that when you closed `vi` (probably by doing control-C, or control-backslash), you caught `vi` right in the middle of outputting some escape sequence. What you see is the last few bytes of that escape sequnce. It shows up as it does because the actual ASCII "ESC" byte never got output, or got output right before the control-C, and the terminal interpreted the control-C as part of the escape sequence. Whatever escape sequence the terminal thought it was interpreting was shorter that the byte sequnce `vi` put out, and you see the remains of the intended escape sequence.

Comment: I think this is pretty close - I think the 0;136;0c looks very like a terminal's response to `\033[6c` or `\033[6n`.